# Collate column instead of replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I need to replace native characters to latin ones. Is it possible to do it with COLLATE?
My code:

```
  SELECT c.Street Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
  from dbo.Customer c
```

doesn' work - I mean column is returned but with no action on it, characters are not latin. How can I change column using COLLATE as to avoid using REPLACE?

Comment: At best a `COLLATE` can change characters into the replacement character (`?`) when operating on a `VARCHAR` value and the characters cannot be represented by that collation. SQL Server contains no native functions or operators for transliterating or converting strings (beyond explicit replacement).

Comment: I tried `SELECT CAST(c.Street AS VARCHAR(80)) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
  from dbo.Customer c` and it worked